# Capture CSV Into Dict when Reading from Subprocess

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, subprocess, pipe

How do I call a subprocess that outputs a CSV to STDOUT, and read that into a dict?

I have a series of scripts that query various management servers, and dump their database to STDOUT as a CSV.  In a separate script, I want to call them, and capture their output into a dict.

This pseudocode shows the concept:

```
NetbrainOutput = subprocess.run(["python3", "../Python:Netbrain/netbrain.py"], capture_output=True)
ZenossOutput = subprocess.run(["python3", "../Python:ZenOSS/zenoss.py"], capture_output=True)

NetbrainCSV = csv.reader(NetbrainOutput)
ZenossCSV = csv.reader(ZenossOutput)
```

Effectively what I'm trying to do is call the subprocess, and connect that subprocess's output to a pipe, which behaves like a file that I can read.  I think know how to convert the CSV into the dict, I don't know how to connect the CSV module to the subprocess output.  Or, maybe I'm going about this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
import sys, subprocess, csv, io

# I developed this on python 3.6
# subprocess module had a fair number of changes around this time
assert sys.version_info >= (3, 6)

script = "ScriptThatOutputsCSV.py"
subprocessPipe = subprocess.Popen(["python3", script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# unfortunately Popen opens the pipe as a binary stream
# DictReader requires a text stream :(
StringIO = io.TextIOWrapper(subprocessPipe.stdout)
reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO)

# unfortunately, list(reader) creates a list of DictReader objects
# we want a list of dicts, so, have to do it the hard way :(
ListedDict = []
for row in reader:
    newDict = {}
    for key in reader.fieldnames:
        newDict[key] = row[key]
    ListedDict.append(newDict)

# ListedDict is now a list of dictionaries
# correlating to the CSV that script sent to STDOUT
```